# Dynamic Trace Plot in R

Tags: r, dynamic, plot

I would like to generate a dynamic plot which draws a new point yet retaining the already traced points. The following code simulates the requirement.

```
seq_x<-seq(1,10)
seq_y<-function(y)
{
z<-y^2+y+1
return (c(z))
}
yrange<-seq_y(1)
yrange[2]<-seq_y(length(seq_x))
for(i in 1:length(seq_x) )
{
xdata<-seq_x[1:i]
ydata<-seq_y(xdata)
plot(xdata,ydata,xlim=range(seq_x),ylim=range(yrange),type="o",col="royalblue",plot.first=grid())
Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

But every time the loop executes, a new plot is generated. *The plot blinks perceptibly (because of the `plot` call in the loop)*. ***How to draw new points to the trace in the same plot so that it appears that the trace is growing in the same window*** ?

Comment: The reason you keep getting a new plot is because "plot" is inside your for loop.

Comment: Yes I know that. _But then how to create the desired effect ?_

Comment: Use `points` or `par(new=TRUE)`. (You cannot change the xlim and ylim that way.)

Comment: This is an old question but have you looked at Cumulative Animations ? More at https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/

Answer (score 0):

As plot.default() generates a new graph each time you should initialize it before the loop and add the points afterwards using points() for example.

This works as I think you need:

```
seq_x<-seq(1,10)
f_y<-function(y){
  z<-y^2+y+1
  return (c(z))
}
seq_y<-f_y(seq_x)
plot(x=seq_x[1],y = seq_y[1], xlim = range(seq_x),ylim=range(seq_y),
     xlab = "x",ylab = "y")
for(i in 1:length(seq_x) ){
  points(seq_x[i],seq_y[i],type="o",col="black")
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```